# Sodoku Backtracking Algorithm

Tags: java, debugging, backtracking

I've written code to generate a Sudoku from a blank grid in Java, using the backtracking method. However i get no output on running the program

```
 public class SodokuGenerator {

int[][] puzzle=new int[9][9];
int num_givens=0;

public static int get_random_value(int high, int low)
{
    //Returns a random value between the given maximum and minimum values(both     inclusive)
    Random r=new Random();
    return (r.nextInt(high+1-low) + low);
}

     public boolean check_column(int x, int y, int curr_value)
{
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if (this.puzzle[i][y]==curr_value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean check_row(int x, int y, int curr_value)
{
    for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if (this.puzzle[x][j]==curr_value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean check_block(int x, int y, int curr_value)
{
    int block_row_start=0, block_row_end=0,block_col_start=0, block_col_end=0;

    if (x==0 || x==3 || x==6)
    {
        block_row_start=x;
        block_row_end=x+3-1;
    }
    else if (x==2 || x==5 || x==8)//At the end of a block
    {
        block_row_start=x-3+1; //both bounds are inclusive
        block_row_end=x;
    }
    else if (x==1 || x==4 || x==7) //Neither multiples of 2 nor 3.
    {
        block_row_start=x-1;
        block_row_end=x+1;
    }

    if (y==0 || y==3 || y==6)
    {
        block_col_start=y;
        block_col_end=y+3-1;
    }
    else if (y==2 || y==5 || y==8)//At the end of a block
    {
        block_col_start=y-3+1; //both bounds are inclusive
        block_col_end=y;
    }
    else if (y==1 || y==4 || y==7) //Neither multiples of 2 nor 3.
    {
        block_col_start=y-1;
        block_col_end=y+1;
    }
    //Established the bounds of the block based on the current position
    //System.out.println("block_row_start="+block_row_start);
    //System.out.println("block_row_end= "+block_row_end);
    for (int i=block_row_start;i<=block_row_end;i++)
    {
        for (int j=block_col_start;j<=block_col_end;j++)
        {
            //System.out.println("i="+i);
            //System.out.println("j="+j);
            if (this.puzzle[i][j]==curr_value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}



public void create_puzzle()
{
    int curr_value=0;
    int index=0;
    int[] possible_values={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    this.puzzle[0][0]=get_random_value(9,1);
    int x=0,y=1; //Holds the coordinates of the current position in the puzzle


    while (x<=8 && y<=8)
    {
        this.puzzle[x][y]=0;
        curr_value= get_random_value(9,1);
        if (this.check_block(x,y, curr_value) &&  this.check_row(x,y,curr_value) 
        && this.check_column(x,y,curr_value))
        {
            this.puzzle[x][y]=curr_value;
        }
        else //If there is a conflict with another element
        {
            index=-1;
            //Checks for a conflict using all possible values
            do //Using a do-while loop prevents a repeated computation
            {
                index++;
                curr_value=possible_values[index];
            }
            while (index<8 && (this.check_block(x,y, curr_value)==false || 
                    this.check_row(x,y,curr_value)==false 
                    || this.check_column(x,y,curr_value)==false));


            if (index==8)//This means that no possible solution was found
            {
                //BACKTRACKING
                if (y==0 && x!=0)
                {
                    y=8;
                    x--;
                }
                else
                {
                    y--;
                }

                continue;
            }
            else //If a possible solution was found
            {
                this.puzzle[x][y]=curr_value;
            }
        }

        //Advancing the current position coordinates to the next position
        if (y==8)
        {
            y=0;
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            y++;
        }
        }
}
```

I did look at similar questions on this forum however they didn't really help me.Debugging tells me that there is an infinite loop at play. Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate it very much. Thank you.

Comment: Adding the rest of your code to the question may help. specially about puzzle.

Comment: @Asher how much time did it take for you to have a solution and code it :). Just a curiosity nothing much

Comment: @Dexters Honestly not too long.. Debugging takes a lot longer :)

Answer (score 0):

while (x<=8 && y<=8)

That loop is infinite. Try printing out the values to the screen within the loop.

System.out.println("X: "+x+" "+y);

I didn't examine your code in-depth...but I suspect the problem to be here:

```
        if (index==8)//This means that no possible solution was found
        {
            //BACKTRACKING
            if (y==0 && x!=0)
            {
                y=8;
                x--;
            }
            else
            {
                y--;
            }

            continue;
        }
```

and

```
if (y==8) //This if statement only runs once. Y always gets subtracted back to 7 in the code above.
    {
         y=0;
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        y++;
    }
    }
```

Once index reaches 8, the function will go into the else, subtracting y by one. Afterwards y is added by one. This process bounces back and fourth, causing the y value to -1 and +1 in an infinite loop.

Comment: you are right. I'm having a really tough time thinking of a suitable alternative though.